# Symfony 3: in my own bundle, my validation.yml is being ignored

Tags: php, validation, symfony

Quite new to Symfony, and trying to get the validator component to work *within my own bundle* using YAML. Some initial debugging steps:

- When I do all of this inside the AppBundle, it works fine (using almost identical YAML, entity, and controller code. Only the namespace/entity name is different)
- To demonstrate that my validation.yml isn't being read by Symfony, I jumbled up the formatting, and Symfony doesn't complain. When I make the same changes in the AppBundle validation.

Here are the most relevant paths:
- Bundle: src/Acme/TestBundle
- Entity: src/Acme/TestBundle/Entity/Person.php
- Validation: src/Acme/TestBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml

Person.php only has a $name property, and no methods. Validation.yml simply has:

```
AcmeTestBundle\Entity\Person:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank: ~
```

In my controller, I'm doing the most basic thing (after instantiating a person object, and without setting the $name property):

```
$v = $this->get('validator');
$errors = $v->validate($myPerson);
```

So it doesn't seem to be getting picked up by Symfony at all. How do I register this YML file with Symfony?

Answer (score -1):

Long story short, this was an issue with the 'NotBlank' constraint and using a POST request.

By default, placing the validation.yml was enough to have it being read, but during all the debugging, I had relocated it. Eventually moved it back, and tried a different constraint, and it's working fine.

Silly me!